# How to execute Url's with on touch listener?

Tags: android

How can i execute a url when button is pressed and when it is released another url is executed.
I used touch listener here is the code but it doesnt work.

```
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.Cam_up:
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                String upUrl = "up";
                task.execute(upUrl);
            } else {
                stop.execute();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.Cam_down:
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                String DownUrl = "down";
                task.execute(DownUrl);
            } else {
                stop.execute();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.Cam_right:
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                String RightUrl = "right";
                task.execute(RightUrl);
            }else {
                stop.execute();
            }
            break;
        case R.id.Cam_left:
            if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {

                String LeftUrl = "left";
                task = new StartRotation();
                task.execute(LeftUrl);
            }else {
                stop.execute();
            }
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

What should i do any solution ??

Comment: What exactly "doesn't work"? Can you post the code for StartRotation? Why is task only instantiated in Cam_left?

Comment: I am using Asynctask as StartRotation Class and Stop rotation as well . To send the request using Url connection. but when i press the button it force closes

Comment: Does it show an error? Can you post the stack trace?